# cPanel, CURL and curl_exec to self issue

Tags: php, curl, cpanel

I have moved site from another server running PLEKS to the server with cPanel. Both servers have installed PHP 5.2.17 with CURL support but after site move to cPanel site is crashing on curl_exec to "self" (part of the web site with blog CMS).

Code for that part looks like:

```
                    # INSTANTIATE CURL.
                        $curl = curl_init();

                        # CURL SETTINGS.
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mydomain.com/news/index.php?tempskin=_rss2");
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);

                        # GRAB THE XML FILE.
                        $xmlData = curl_exec($curl);

                        curl_close($curl);

                        # SET UP XML OBJECT.
                        $xmlObjData = simplexml_load_string( $xmlData );

                        $tempCounter = 0;

                        foreach ( $xmlObjData->channel->item as $item )
                        {                    
                            # DISPLAY ONLY 10 ITEMS.
                            if ( $tempCounter < 10 )
                            {
                                echo "<li><a href=\"{$item -> link}\">{$item -> title}</a></li>
                        ";
                            }

                            $tempCounter += 1;
                        }

                         ?>
```

Any clue why cPanel server can't handle that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through server configuration as well firewall got it solved with creating a loopback NAT.

Answer (score 0):

On cPanel there are two php binaries. So please confirm and check for extension by `php -m | grep curl`. If it is not available you will have to compile php again with EasyApache option in WHM to enabling curl.

Comment: It returns `Wrong parameter count for curl_error()`. Any clue?

Comment: Also EasyApache profile details says: `CurlSSL
This option will make the following changes to your profile prior to the build: Disables: Curl` Maybe I need to disable CurlSSL and enable Curl?

Comment: `curl_error ($curl)` - no error message. You can take a look at www.rosica.com Latest News & Press section

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting `string(24) "couldn't connect to host"`, but I can execute `http://www.rosica.com/news/index.php?tempskin=_rss2` in the browser

Comment: I just tried from my browser, its blocked. May be its a firewall issue.

Error :
`Gateway GEO-IP/BOTNET Alert

This request is blocked by the SonicWALL Gateway Geo IP Service. Country Name:India Initiator IP:*.*.*.58` (whole ip is displayed)

Comment: Turned off IPS on SonicWall - check if you can get now.

Comment: I think it must be some kind of SonicWall issue not letting connect to itself because connection to google.com was executed promptly.

Comment: Well, SonicWall tested and is not blocking cURL. No clue what next to test :\

Comment: I found that wget is not working from any domain behind the firewall to any domain which are also behind that firewall. Strange..